# Adding lists by reference

Tags: python, list, reference

Is it possible to add two lists using a reference of each list instead of a copy?

For example -

```
first_list = [1,2,3]
second_list = [5,6]
new_list = first_list + second_list
print(new_list)    # Will print [1,2,3,5,6]
first_list.append(4)
print(new_list)    # Should print [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Is there a way to do this in Python? Or is code re-write my only option?

Edit: I removed confusing comments I made about using C++ to do this.

Comment: "I am thinking in terms of C++ and how pointers can be used to do this" - neither `std::vector` nor `std::list` supports this, for similar reasons to why Python doesn't support it either.

Comment: My apologies. I was talking about how arrays can be referenced. Is there a different data structure in Python that can help me do this? I am not bound by lists.

Comment: Your question makes less sense after that clarification, not more. Can you edit the question to (a) explain things better, and (b) show us the C++ code you had in mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly do this in Python any more than you can in C++.

But you can indirectly do it in Python the exact same way you can in C++: by writing an object that holds onto both lists and dispatches appropriately.

For example:

```
class TwoLists(collections.abc.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = a, b
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.a) + len(self.b)
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # cheating a bit, not handling slices or negative indexing
        if idx < len(self.a):
            return self.a[idx]
        else:
            return self.b[idx - len(self.a)]
```

Now:

```
>>> first_list = [1,2,3]
>>> second_list = [5,6]
>>> two_lists = TwoLists(first_list, second_list)
>>> print(*two_lists)
1 2 3 5 6
>>> first_list.append(4)
>>> print(*two_lists)
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

---

What I think you were missing here is a fundamental distinction between Python and C++ in how variables work. Briefly, every Python variable (and attribute and list position and so on) is, in C++ terms, a reference variable.

Less misleadingly:

C++ variables (and attributes, etc.) are memory locations—they're where values live. If you want `a` to be a reference to the value in `b`, you have to make a reference-to-b value, and store that in `a`. (C++ has a bit of magic that lets you *define* a reference variable like `int& a = b`, but you can't later reassign `a` to refer to `c`; if you want that, you have to explicitly use pointers, C-style.)

Python variables (and etc.) are names for values, while the values live wherever they want to. If you want `a` to be a reference to the value in `a`, you just bind `a` to the same value `b` is bound to: `a = b`. (And, unlike C++, you can reassign `a = c` at any time.)

Of course the cost is performance: there's an extra indirection to reach any value from its name in Python, while in C++, that only happens when you use pointer variables. But that cost is pretty much always invisible compared to the other overhead of Python (interpreting bytecode and dynamically looking names up in dictionaries and so on), so it makes sense for a high-level language to just not give you the choice.

---

All that being said, there's usually not a good reason to do this in *either* language. Both Python, and the C++ standard library, are designed around (similar, but different notions of) iteration.

In Python, you usually don't actually need a sequence, just an iterable. And to chain two iterables together is trivial:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> first_list = [1,2,3]
>>> second_list = [5,6]
>>> print(*chain(first_list, second_list))
1 2 3 5 6
>>> first_list.append(4)
>>> print(*chain(first_list, second_list))
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Yes, I can only iterate over the `chain` once, but usually that's all you need. (Just as in C++ you usually only need to loop from `begin(c)` to `end(c)`, not to build a new persistent object that holds onto them.)

And if you think that's cheating because I'm using `itertools`, we can define it ourselves:

```
def chain(*its):
    for it in its:
        yield from it
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.